# How can I have a dictionary using objects as keys?

Tags: typescript

I try to have a dictionary using objects as keys:

```js
api: {[key: string]: string} = {
  getItems: 'api/v1/items/all'
};
```

If I try to use it `var urlpath = api.getItems;` I get:

> Property 'getItems' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: string;`
>   }.

If I change the key's type to any `{[key: any]: string}`, I get:

> An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.

I can use it like this, but that's not what I want:

```js
var urlpath = api['getItems'];
```

**How can I have a dictionary using objects as keys?**

Comment: You have to create an interface or class with all params you want it to have including getItems. Then you declare api as an object of that type. If you declare the way you are doing it now Typescript won't understand it because it has no interface

Comment: @iberbeu your suggestion works, though it would be nice to not need the interface. Do you now why typesricpt does not understand this?

Comment: Because it is a typed language. That means you always need to define an interface for each object. This is actually what you are looking for when moving to typescript, that when you try to code the way you did it, you get an error message. If you still want to do it that way then you should give typescript away and keep working directly with JS

Comment: In my mind the type of key could be any class: `{[key: MyClass]: string}`. In this case type saefty would still apply. I was refering to you if you know why this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the wonderful library created by @basarat and named "typescript-collections". Kindly find the link below:
[typescript collections](https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections)

What you need is just install it with the following command:

```
npm install typescript-collections
```

It also contains all the necessary definitions just to make code experience better.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps...

TypescriptDictionary.ts

```
export interface typescriptDictionary {
    getItems: string;    
    getItem2: string;
}

export class TypescriptDictionary implements typescriptDictionary {

    private _getItems: string;
    private _getItem2: string;

    constructor (item: string, item2: string ) {
          this._getItems = item;
          this._getItem2 = item2;
    }


    public get getItems(): string {
          return this._getItems;
    }

    public get getItem2(): string {
          return this._getItem2;
    }
}
```

To use TypescriptDictionary.ts, import its interface and class, create a variable of type IfcTypescriptDictionary.ts, initialize it using class constructor and access its different types using same variable.

DemoUsage.ts

```
import {IfcTypescriptDictionary} from 'filePath';
import {TypescriptDictionary} from 'filePath';

export class UseDemo {

    var dictionary: IfcTypescriptDictionary;

    // initialize it with its class constructor.

    dictionary = new TypescriptDictionary('demo text', 'demo text1');

    // access it using
    console.log(dictionary.getItems);
    console.log(dictionary.getItems2);
}
```

Regards

Ajay

Answer (score 0):

A solution:

```
const api: {[key: string]: string; getItems: string} = {
  getItems: 'api/v1/items/all'
};
```

[Indexable types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) are made in order to be used with the operator `[]`. They enforce type checking with this operator:

```
api['abc'] = 123; // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

They don't provide a way to access to any arbitrary member name `api.abc`.

Comment: @lambdagreen You can use `const api: any`, but you loose the type checking.